Prove that in the canonical basis $\mathrm{grad}\,f = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\,e_i$.
Reading Do Carmo I found this exercise:

Given a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ the vector field (gradient) is defined by
$$ \langle \mathrm{grad}\,f(p) \rangle =df_p(u) $$
for all $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and all $u \in \mathbb{R}^n_{p}$. Prove that in the canonical basis
$$\mathrm{grad}\,f = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\,e_i\,. $$

My approach:
Let $e_i$, be fixed, then we get
\begin{align*}
\langle \mathrm{grad}\,f(p), e_1 \rangle &= df_p(e_1) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\\
\langle \mathrm{grad}\,f(p), e_2 \rangle &= df_p(e_2) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},\\
&\vdots\\
\langle \mathrm{grad}\,f(p), e_n \rangle &= df_p(e_n) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}.
\end{align*}
Here we have $n$ components, but I still don't know that these correspond with the gradient, in here I just get nowhere to go.

What does the notation $\langle \mathrm{grad},f(p) \rangle$ mean? It seems you're using this both for a vector and an inner product?

Yes it is meant inner product.

Let $v\in\Bbb R^n$ be some vector and $\mathcal B=\{e_i\}$ is any O.N. basis. Then it's always true that the vector $v$ can be expanded as follows (using inner products with the basis vectors):
$$ v = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v,e_i\rangle\,e_i\,. \tag{1} $$
Thus, for your problem, it suffices to show that for some fixed $e_j\in\mathcal B$, we have
$$ \langle \mathrm{grad}\,f(p), e_j \rangle = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \,, $$
holds for each $1\le j\le n$, which is exactly what you have done. So, if you can convince yourself that $(1)$ is true for $\Bbb R^n$, you're done.

$(1)$ does not hold for any basis. The basis must be orthonormal.

@azif00 : Yes, that's exactly what I meant to say. Edited to reflect this.
